# Boost compilation error

Tags: c++, boost, compilation

I am trying to compile my boost simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void workerFunc(const char* msg, float delay_ms)
{
boost::posix_time::milliseconds workTime(delay_ms);

std::cout << "Worker: running, message = " << msg << std::endl;

// Pretend to do something useful...
boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);

std::cout << "Worker: finished" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
std::cout << "main: startup" << std::endl;

boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc, "Hello, Boost!", 2.5e3);

std::cout << "main: waiting for thread" << std::endl;

workerThread.join();

std::cout << "main: done" << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

using g++ with this command

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

but i get an error like this:

```
main.cpp: In function `void workerFunc(const char*, float)':
main.cpp:7: error: `boost::posix_time' has not been declared
main.cpp:7: error: `milliseconds' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:7: error: expected `;' before "workTime"
main.cpp:12: error: `boost::this_thread' has not been declared
main.cpp:12: error: `workTime' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:21: error: no matching function for call to `boost::thread::thread(void (&)(const char*, float), const char[14], double)'
/usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:35: note: candidates are: boost::thread::thread(const boost::thread&)
/usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:38: note:                 boost::thread::thread(const boost::function0<void, std::allocator<boost::function_base> >&)
/usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:37: note:                 boost::thread::thread()
```

What's wrong and how should i compile it...?

Comment: Is libboost-date-time-dev installed?

Comment: How to check it...? Sorry for my stupid questions, but I'm not so familiar with linux...

Answer (score 7):

According to this

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html

You need this

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"
```

Comment: That's cool, but now it gives "error: `boost::this_thread' has not been declared"...

Comment: I gave you the link to the documentation which gives the header for anything you are using.  If you search in it, you will get the answer.

Comment: According to this http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread I should include #include <boost/thread/thread.hpp> but this doesn't solve the problem...:(

Comment: According to your error, it's in /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp -- if you don't have 1.45.0, then either install it or use the documentation for the version you have.

Comment: That was the problem - I have an early version - 1.32 - so many things weren't implemented yet... Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have an old version of Boost installed in your system. Read the file `/usr/include/boost/version.hpp`. And depending on which version you have, consult the version specific documentation (see [Boost Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/)). Or install the latest version of Boost by either using you system's packaging functionality, if available, or manually following the install directions (see [Getting Started on Unix Variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Since the compiler doesn't recognize some type, it means that you are missing some includes.

For posix_time you need to add `#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"` on top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the header declaring posix_time. Look at the boost doc to see which it is (you can try `#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_system.hpp"` but I'm not sure that would be enough).